# Using iOS pan gesture to highlight buttons in grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

So far I have a grid of buttons and have attached a pan gesture recognizer to the view. I can track the events and get the location of the finger as it moves but there doesn't seem to be the equivalent of a "mouseEnter" message to use to get info about or control properties (such as the highlighting) of the other buttons I pass over.

Am I missing something? How can I accomplish, say, highlighting the buttons under the users' fingers as they pan over them? Does cocoa touch support this or must something else be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code and write what is the problem in the code

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find the proper code to write. I am looking for the calls that enable me to touchUpInside a button, keep my finger down, drag it over buttons in the grid and have feedback on which buttons I am over during the move. I'm not finding that and am asking what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, there is no such event. Also UIButton events won't help you either, because those require to actually start gesture inside. What you can do instead is to get location of the point you are currently dragging:

```
func panDetected(sender : MoreInformativeGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view)
}
```

And now, when you have the point, you can iterate on all the buttons you have and check if the point is inside the button:

```
let buttons = [UIButton]
let lastActiveButton = UIButton?

...

// Iterate through all the buttons
for button in buttons {

   // Check area of the button against your touch
   if CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, touchPoint) {

      // You are inside the touch area of the button
      // Here, you can for example perform some action if you want, store information
      // about the button so you don't do it multiple times etc.. your call :)
      self.lastActiveButton = button
   }
}
```

This way you can detect then you go in and out and do whatever you want with events. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is very helpful.

Comment: @Jiri Trecak - I stumbled across this post in an attempt to solve my own issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064963/slide-finger-across-3-buttons-xcode-swift/38065168#38065168 - your solution above gave me the best results so far, but would you mind taking a look at my post? you seem to have the knowledge to fully nail what i'm looking for. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

UIButton inherits from UIControl which has a number of [events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events)

Have you tried that? You can add a listener to those events, either through nib/storyboard or through code (look under discussion to see how to do this)