# Slide finger across 3 buttons - Xcode & Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, swift2, slide

I have 3 buttons in my UI that ultimately will perform similar to keys on a piano. Either of the 3 buttons may get tapped to perform that particular buttons actions, but the user can 'slide' their finger off onto the next button to perform button 2's action.

I did some searching and it looks like a touchesBegan method detecting the location of the tap is best. My attempt is below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
```

*(I don't have any action events tied to the 3 buttons, because I thought touchesBegan will cover that.)*

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var touch: UITouch = event!.allTouches()!.first!
    var location: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(touch.view!)
    if CGRectContainsPoint(button1.frame, location){
        print("button 1")
    }
    else if CGRectContainsPoint(button2.frame, location) {
        print("button 2")
    }
    else if CGRectContainsPoint(button3.frame, location) {
        print("button 3")
    }

}
```

Nothing prints to the console when I test this. I tested both tapping and swiping across buttons. Should I be using UIViews instead of UIButtons? Should I be using actions on the buttons? This is for Swift 2.0. Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have a working prototype much closer to how I envisioned this functioning. This thread here: [Using iOS pan gesture to highlight buttons in grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584514/using-ios-pan-gesture-to-highlight-buttons-in-grid) pointed me in the direction of using a pangesture on the buttons superview.

```
var touchPoint = CGPoint()
var myGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
```

viewDidLoad:

```
    myGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("panDetected:"))
    myGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(myGesture)
```

.

```
func panDetected(sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    touchPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view)


        if CGRectContainsPoint(button1.frame, touchPoint) {
            button1Func()
        }

        else if CGRectContainsPoint(button2.frame, touchPoint) {
            button2Func()
        }

        else if CGRectContainsPoint(button3.frame, touchPoint) {
            button3Func()
        }
```

The above DOES work, however, button1Func / button2Func / button3Func all contain an animation block. When the finger is dragged within the buttons, it fires the method every time a movement is detected. I just need for this to happen once. I tried adding this to a state == .Began statement, but that prevents any functionality once the finger leaves the first tapped button.

Is there any way I can fire those methods (button1Func / button2Func / button3Func) just ONCE inside the pan gesture once the finger is inside the bounds of each of the 3 buttons? I will be happy to clarify this if it's confusing. THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole bunch of control events you can tie to IBActions. Take a look at the `UIControlEvents` enum. You probably want to add actions for `UIControlEventTouchDragInside`, `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` and a few others.

Comment: I have tried every possible combination I could think of with UIControlEvents... https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents#symbols - Nothing registers a seemless action transition from one button slide to the next. When you say "and a few others" can you be more specific? I'm afraid this route is taking me down a potentially very bloated viewcontroller. Was hoping to use outlets, like in my code attempt above, as it's considerably more manageable

Comment: I haven't tried to do what you are doing, so I would have to experiment. Using touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded on the superView that contains the buttons would work too, and might make the code cleaner than trying to attach a bunch of target/actions to your buttons to detect the various cases of tapping/sliding.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I'm very close to the desired result, but having a quirky result with a pangesture.